# How can I get tall the index of a substring occurrence in mysql

Tags: mysql, substring, indexof, substr, locate

I have a column with values `111001`, `111111`
I need to get all the index of occurrence of 1. How can I achieve that

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify.

Comment: are you looking for the count of ones in a Coleman?

Comment: not at all clear what is meant by ""get tall the index of" or "get all the index of". consider editing the question to add an example of expected result, for the values given.